# How to identify dynamic listview row separately to identify which row has been clicked

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am fiddling with a google map tutorial where I have a map populated dynamically with markers of values from a database using JSON. As well as this I have a listview also dynamically populated with the names of each marker from the same database. I am trying to pan to the location of the marker's lat and lon when the the name of the store in the listview is selected.

Eg. The user selects McDonalds in the listview. They are then panned to the McDonald's marker location on the map.

I imagine that the id from each row in the listview should somehow be used to match the lat and lon values in the array and then used the map.panTo() function of the store's lat and long. I am a novice with JSON so unsure of how to do this as it's all dynamic and it's all stuck in a loop.

jQuery for the dynamic listview is posted below.

**JS**

```
var file = "getsome.php";

$.post(file, function(data) {

var output = '';

$.each(data, function(index, value){ 

    output += '<li><a href="#" id='+ value.site_id +'" class="latlon">' + value.site_name + '</a></li>';

}); $('#listview-id').html(output).listview().listview('refresh'); }, "json");
```

**getsome.php**

```
require("dbconnect.php");

try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $username, $password,
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
}
 catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM Site WHERE 1");

$STH->execute();

$result = $STH->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method. In the example i grab some data from the  Listview item using (closest). While you dynamically populate the listview items you can insert data attributes -- data-whatever="the data" -- eg (data-address="10 maple Street" data-lat="45.6789" data-lng="56.6786") etc

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/g5tvj3xp/

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="listview">
    <li data-id="row1">Row 1</li>
    <li data-id="row2">Row 2</li>
    <li data-id="row3">Row 3</li>
    <li data-id="row4">Row 4</li>
</ul>


$("#listview").on("click", ">li", function(event, ui) {
var id = $(this).closest("li").attr('data-id');
alert(id)
});
```

Comment: Awesome :) I didn't realise it could be so simple. Thanks very much @Tasos